# Sum of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {x^n}{(n-1)!} $

Tags: summation

the task is to find sum of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {x^n}{(n-1)!} $. I've tried to factor out $x$ to get $x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {{x}^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}$  and integrate the sum, which yields $x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {x^n}{n!} $ which I can sum as $xe^x$. Then I need to derivate it which yields $e^x+xe^x$. The correct answer is supposed to be $xe^x$. What step am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: To see where your solution has a mistake, try writing out the integration.  However, there is a solution that does not involve integrating or differentiating at all.

Comment: The "correct" answer is not correct. Your is good !

Comment: @ Tomáš Svoboda You integrate the sum (up to constant)  and differenciate  the sum multiplied by x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you have to integrate the complete expression $x\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}$ if you want to use integration. We then obtain by using *[integration by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts)*
\begin{align*}
\int \underbrace{x}_{u}\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}}_{v^\prime}\,dx
&= x\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n}}{n!}-\int  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{n}}{n!}\,dx\\
&=x\left(e^x-1\right)-\int \left(e^x-1\right)\,dx\\
&=x\left(e^x-1\right)-e^x+x+C\\
&=xe^x-e^x+C\tag{1}
\end{align*}
and differentiation of (1) gives
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}\left(xe^x-e^x+C\right)&=\left(e^x+xe^x\right)-e^x\\
&=xe^x
\end{align*}
as wanted.

> More convenient is reindexing the series. This way we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{(n-1)!}}&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^{n+1}}{n!}=x\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}
> \color{blue}{=xe^x}
> \end{align*}

Comment: @TomášSvoboda: You're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

By reindexing, we see that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac {{x}^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac {{x}^{n}}{(n)!}$$

Comment: It is not a complete answer, and does not say more then the comments...